# I want to write a Google App Script to automate calculating late days in Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I want to write a code that automate the late days calculation. Here is how it should work

- If the score of date after (ex: date 10) - score of day before (date 9)> 0 => the score of date after (120) will be assigned "late for 3 days"
- On the other hand, that date after will keep looking and substracting from the next date before until it gets "> 0" result.

The example is illustrated in attached image.

Here is the code that I currently have and it didnt work:

```
function myFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.geActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  
  for (var i=2; i <= 8; i++){
  var scoreafterCell = activeSheet.getRange(i;2).getValue();
  var scorebeforeCell= activeSheet.getRange(i++;2).getValue();
    
  scoreDiff= scoreafterCell- scorebeforeCell;
    
    if(scoreDiff > 0) {
      activeSheet.getRange(i,3).setValue(3);
    } else for (var k=0; k++) {
      do {
      
      lateDays= k+=3;
      activeSheet.getRange(i,3).setValue(lateDays);
    }
      while (scoreDiff = 0);
            }
          }
      }
```

Hope to have some inputs soon since this is very important for my work!!! Thank you.

Comment: Here is the example in case the attached one does not work: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fa4z89MCmMPY7SedOk3t7IxX6Qrff_QK936RXNXWF1M/edit#gid=0

Comment: I have provided an answer below @levi510, kindly check when you're available.

Comment: If your question was solved, please push the accept button. Other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no clear pattern above, I did a hack to achieve what you want. This only checks the scores and doesn't check the dates as `lateDays` won't be dependent on that.

Please see the code below.

```
function generateLateDays() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
  var scores = activeSheet.getRange('B2:B' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var output = activeSheet.getRange('C2:C' + lastRow);
  
  var lateDays = [];
  while(scores.length > 0) {
    // get how many occurences does the first element have
    occurence = scores.filter(value => value === scores[0]).length;
    // remove current item in advance, we will only be checking number of occurences
    // exact value will not be checked, so scores should be in descending order
    scores = scores.filter(score => score !== scores[0]);
    
    // contains per score late days
    var temp = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < occurence; j++) {
      if(scores.length > 0) {
        // e.g. 3 duplicates will make temp 3, 4, 5 
        temp.push(j + 3);
      }
      else {
        // when last element is up, push 0
        temp.push(0);
      }
    }
    // e.g. temp reverse will be 5, 4, 3
    temp.reverse();
    // add to final output
    lateDays.push(temp);
  }
  // convert 2d array to 1d array
  lateDays = lateDays.flat();
  for(var i = 0; i < lateDays.length; i++) {
    // convert all elements into an array for setValues
    lateDays[i] = [].concat(lateDays[i]);
  }
  output.setValues(lateDays);
}
```

Note that this will work only on the order your sample sheet works. I haven't tried doing it ascending. Since your sheet score descending, I made this to work that way.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask below.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my suggested answer. Check it out:

```js
function getLateDates() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var scores = activeSheet.getRange('B2:B10').getValues().flat();
  var output = activeSheet.getRange('D2:D10');

  /**
   * Set LateDates[_] as array of 3,
   * except the last value = 0 ( at t = 0 )
   *
   */
  let LateDates = [
    ...Array.from({ length: scores.length - 1 }).map((x) => 3),
    0,
  ];

  /** Check the diff of current score with each of the next score,
   * if diff > 0 --> break --> LateDates[current] = 3
   * if diff = 0 --> +1 to LateDates[current], and continue w the next score
   *
   */
  for (var current = 0; current < scores.length; current++) {
    for (var next = current + 1; next < scores.length; next++) {
      let d = scores[current] - scores[next];
      if (d > 0) {
        break;
      } else {
        LateDates[current]++;
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Reduce the LateDates to fit setValues format
   */
  let result = LateDates.reduce((a,c)=> ([...a,[c]]),[])
  output.setValues(result)
  //console.log('result', result);
}
```

Notice I'm using your date order (descending).
If it's ascending, switch 0 to top of `LateDates[]` instead:

```
let LateDates = [
    0,
    ...Array.from({ length: scores.length - 1 }).map((x) => 3),
  ];
```